# Telemetry GrpcExporter : Failed to export metrics in Hyperledger Fabric Gateway (Java)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java, open-telemetry-java

my Hyperledger Fabric Gateway (HLF 2.2.2) for Java client app connects to the Fabric network OK and works without any problems, but my log file is full of these entries:

```
2024-02-23T14:51:19.534+01:00  WARN 1 --- [alhost:4317/...] i.o.exporter.internal.grpc.GrpcExporter  : Failed to export metrics. Server responded with gRPC status code 2. Error message: Failed to connect to localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:4317
```

How can I disable this metric exporting that I don't need?

Answer (score 0):

Adding env variable OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER with value "none" disables it.